# Matlab Pade approximation influence on bode plot and step response

Tags: matlab, control-systems, delay

I would like to approximate a delay via the pade approximation. I set a normal delay via the exponential term and I set a delay via the pade approximation and I look the difference between the both with a bode plot and a step response. This is totaly different ... So this is not an approximation ... Where is my error ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to properly select a time vector for the step function. I suspect that Matlab has trouble automatically selecting a good time vector for small delays.

try this

```
close all;
clear all;
clc;

s = tf('s');

sys_retard = exp(-2E-6*s);
sys_retard_pade = pade(sys_retard, 3);

T = linspace(0, 10*2E-6, 1000);

figure(1);
output1 = step(sys_retard, T);
output2 = step(sys_retard_pade, T);
figure
plot(T, output1,'b', T, output2,'r');
```

[image]

Edit :

Try the same thing for your bode plot. Select the frequency vector yourself and aim for a good resolution.

Comment: The same probably also holds for the frequency vector in the Bode plot.

Comment: yeah, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

The [Padé approximation technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) seeks to find a rational transfer function that matches the Taylor series expansion of the function being approximated to as many terms as possible.  [From what the Matlab manual says](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/pade.html), it looks like this is what the `pade` method is doing.

If you want the approximant to match the Bode plot, use a different approximation technique. If you want the approximant to match the step responds, also use a different technique.